# plotting only time using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame like this:

```
 head(yy)
    Team       Date STime ETime
1    A 2012-03-06 07:03 10:13
2    A 2012-03-06 07:03 10:13
3    A 2012-03-06 07:03 10:13
4    A 2012-03-06 07:03 10:13
5    A 2012-03-06 07:03 10:13
6    A 2012-03-06 07:03 10:13
```

dput(yy)

```
dput(yy)
structure(list(Team = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), 
Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2012-03-06", class = "factor"), 
STime = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "07:03", class = "factor"), 
ETime = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "10:13", class = "factor")), .Names = c("Team", 
"Date", "STime", "ETime"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
```

I like to see the y-axis from 00:00 23:59 in 2 hours increment and be able to draw a red line on STime value.

I have somthing like this but it does not look right:

```
ggplot(yy, aes(Date, ETime, group="Team")) + geom_jitter(size=0.05) + facet_wrap( ~ Team) + geom_hline(yintercept=yy$Stime, colour="red", size=2)
```

[image]
how would you do this in ggplot2? Can somebody give me pointers/start me in the right direction?

Regards,

Comment: Could you post the result `dput(df)` (or `dput(head(df))` if it's too big) so we can reproduce your data?

Comment: @DavidRobinson, I just placed the dput output.

Comment: There is no variation in your data. If you are simply trying to produce an illustration you should take a look a [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) it's a great piece of free software–like R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to format your times into actual times.  Right now they are factors (Check your data frame with `str(yy)`).  When ETime is plotted, the single time is plotted as 1 and labeled "10:13."   So, the solution below first converts the string "10:13" into a time (`strptime`) then converts it to `POSIXct`, or seconds since an origin (1/1/1970).

```
library(ggplot2); library(scales)

#Convert date string into POSIXct format
yy$STime <- as.POSIXct(strptime(yy$STime, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC"))
yy$ETime <- as.POSIXct(strptime(yy$ETime, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC"))

#Define y-axis limits
lims <- as.POSIXct(strptime(c("0:00","23:59"), format = "%H:%M", tz= "UTC"))    

ggplot(yy, aes(Date, ETime, group="Team")) + geom_jitter(size=1) + facet_wrap( ~ Team) + 
  geom_hline(data = yy, aes(yintercept= as.numeric(STime)), colour="red", size=2) + 
  scale_y_datetime(limits =lims, breaks=date_breaks("2 hour"),
                   labels=date_format("%H:%M", tz = "UTC") )
```

[image: datetime y-axis]
Note on [geom_line to date axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30970521/4718512).

Pay attention to your timezones too.  Otherwise R/ggplot will format things according to your local time zone.