# ggplot geom_line to date axis not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

I have several data-sets similar to https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9ihawgfqwxmkgc/pred.csv?dl=0

Loading them from CSV and then plotting works fine

```
predictions$date <- as.Date(predictions$date)
plot(predictions$date, predictions$pct50)
```

But when I want to use GGPLOT to draw these data predicted points into a plot to compare them with the original points like:

```
p = ggplot(theRealPastDataValues,aes(x=date,y=cumsum(amount)))+geom_line()
```

This command

```
p + geom_line(predictions, aes(x=as.numeric(date), y=pct50))
```

generates the following error:

```
ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval
```

But as the first `plot(predictions$date, predictions$pct50)` works with the data I do not understand what is wrong.

## Edit

```
dput(predictions[1:10, c("date", "pct50")])
structure(list(date = c("2009-07-01", "2009-07-02", "2009-07-03", 
"2009-07-04", "2009-07-05", "2009-07-06", "2009-07-07", "2009-07-08", 
"2009-07-09", "2009-07-10"), pct50 = c(4276, 4076, 4699.93, 4699.93, 
4699.93, 4699.93, 4664.76, 4627.37, 4627.37, 4627.37)), .Names = c("date", 
"pct50"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

## Edit 2

I change this

```
p + geom_line(data = predictions, aes(x=as.numeric(date), y=pct50))
```

and the error changed to:

```
Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
Zusätzlich: Warning message:
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs created
```

so I think the hint to [How to deal with "data of class uneval" error from ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486819/how-to-deal-with-data-of-class-uneval-error/16486873#16486873) (see comments) was a good Idea, bit still the plot does not work.

Comment: `?geom_line` shows the first argument is `mapping = NULL`. Try explicitly stating that `data = predictions`

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16486873/4002530) is similar

Comment: thank you @tospig - see edit2 your hint went into the right direction but the plot still does not work

Comment: your `predictions$date` is a character vector, and when using `as.numeric` it introduces `NAs`. If you want numerics you may need `as.numeric(as.Date(predictions$date), format="%Y%m%d")`

Comment: But you may then get issues with trying to use different values on the x-axis

Comment: @tospig - your are right p + geom_line(data = predictions, aes(x=as.Date(date), y=pct50))
 does the job. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'll write an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first issue (Edit 2) is because `?geom_line` uses `mapping=NULL` as the first argument, so you need to explicitely state the first argument is `data`

```
p + geom_line(data = predictions, aes(x=as.numeric(date), y=pct50))
```

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16486873/4002530)

Your second issue is because your `predictions$date` is a character vector, and when using as.numeric it introduces `NA`s. If you want numerics you need to format it as a date first, then convert it to numeric

```
as.numeric(as.Date(predictions$date), format="%Y%m%d")
```